# About DB Relations And Indexes

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have three tables and they have a total of 2 million rows.

I'm creating a SQL query with inner join with two , sometimes three tables together. Sometimes I'm just creating a SQL query for one table.

I want to create index for it, but I'm not sure how can I create. How should I do it ? Three columns (all ID columns in tables) together or seperated. And which index will works fine ?

The last question is about DB relations. This three tables doesn't have a PF-FK relationship. Can it effect for my query time ?

If you can help me, thanks for it :)

Answer (score 0):

With so little data about your model I can suggest this:

Create an index for each column on each table that is used in a join

If you want more suggestions you need to give more information.